# Angular Component Debugging

Tags: angular6

I am new to angular and I has been assigned with a bug in which input-text is showing some invalid values. I need to figure out from which component and from which UI code it is getting generated.? Can any one suggest quick approach for this

Answer (score 0):

To create a form validation for angular you can use one of these two methods:

- Method one using ngmodel use the [angular ngmodel form validation](https://angular.io/guide/forms)
- Use form FormControl [Formcontrol](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form)

I hope that can help you to resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Comment: welcome welcome start testing and if you have any questions let me know .